# Is there a EOS tumbler or coinjoin service to obfuscate my coins and addresses?

Tags: privacy

I find it very annoying that users can easily see my trading activity on dapps and how much I own and which accounts I have. Is there a service that obfuscates my EOS and tokens that can tumble or coinjoin it through a few accounts? I know its not fool proof if one were to do the legwork to find out where your coins ended up, but it at least prevents a simple block explorer lookup which anyone can easily do.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at the pEOS token for private transactions:

https://peos.one/

Comment: That only hides the PEOS token, not your eos balance or anything else associated with your account.